# Product of fundamental matrices $G(x)^{-1} H(x)$ does not depend on $x$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, matrix-equations

Recently I posted a book exercises about fundamental matrices I managed to solve. The following one is a little harder imo:

> Let $G(x)$ and $H(x)$ be fundamental matrices of the homogeneous linear system of equations
> $$
> y^{\prime}=A(x) y.
> $$
> Show: $G(x)^{-1} H(x)$ does not depend on $x$.

---

I played a little bit around with the equations:

If $G(x)$ and $H(x)$ are fundamental matrices, then
$$
G^\prime(x)=A(x)G(x)
$$
and
$$
H^\prime(x)=A(x)H(x).
$$
Then
$$
G^\prime(x)G(x)^{-1}=A(x)=H^\prime(x)H(x)^{-1}
$$
and
$$
G(x)^{-1}H(x)=A(x)H(x)G^\prime(x)^{-1}=H^\prime(x)G^\prime(x)^{-1}.
$$

But it got me nowhere and I wanted to ask for some help. Thanks in advance for any kind of hint or help.

Comment: if the matrix is independent of x then its derivative is zero and vis versa

Comment: vis versa $\to$ vice versa...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take the derivative with respect to x

$f(x)=G(x)^{-1}H(x) \Rightarrow f'(x)=\frac{d~(G(x)^{-1})}{dx}H(x)+G(x)^{-1}H'(x)$

$\frac{d~(G(x)^{-1})}{dx}=-G(x)^{-1}G'(x)G(x)^{-1}$

$\Rightarrow f'(x)=-G(x)^{-1}G'(x)G(x)^{-1}H(x)+G(x)^{-1}H'(x) = -G(x)^{-1}A(x)H(x)+G(x)^{-1}H'(x) = -G(x)^{-1}H'(x)+G(x)^{-1}H'(x)=0 \Rightarrow f(x)=constant$